# In Corona/ Lua how to display a number on an image?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am creating a game where there are a lot of egg images dropping down and there are randomly generated numbers displayed on them. When the eggs are tapped, I need to retrieve the number associated with it. The following is my code

```
local myRandomNumber = math.random(0,10) 
local egg=display.newImage("egg.jpg")
egg.numberValue=myRandomNumber
```

Right now I have the number associated to the egg image, but I wanted the numberValue(i.e the random number generated) to be displayed on the image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code to do so. Add it below Your code.

```
local eggText = display.newText({x = egg.x, y = egg.y, text = tostring(egg.numberValue), fontSize = 15, font = native.systemFont })
eggGroup :insert(egg)
eggGroup :insert(eggText)
```

Then just do transition on eggGroup instead of on 'egg'

Comment: Wowww that was awesome...it solved my problem..thankyou!!